# Change color of yerr in time series plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Built a time series model with facebook prophet but I am trying to plot the forecast with confidence intervals or y_hat lower, y_hat upper. I have the year right but I'm trying to change the color or the alpha of the yerr to make it visible.

```
ax = pro_la.plot(x ='ds', y='y',figsize = (12,8))
ax =forecast_low.plot(x='ds',y='yhat',color = 'green', yerr = 17, xlim=('2020-01-01','2021-04-30'), ylim = (0,275),figsize = (12,8), ax=ax)
set();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `.errorbar(x,y,yerr,xerr)` instead of `.plot()`. That way you will get an errorbar for every data point you put into your graph.